# What conditions must hold to have a valid integral transform and associated inverse transform?

Tags: integral-transforms

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_transform), an integral transform is any transform $T$ of the following form:
$$(Tf)(u) = \int_{t_1}^{t_2}f(t)K(t, u)dt.$$

The inverse transform is of the following form:
$$f(t) = \int_{u_1}^{u_2}(Tf)(u)K^{-1}(u, t)du.$$

What conditions must hold to have a valid integral transform and associated inverse transform?

The Wikipedia page goes on: "every integral transform is a linear operator". Therefore, we can represent an integral transform as matrix $A$ and its associated inverse transform as matrix $A'$. What properties do matrices $A$ and $A'$ have?

Comment: You can follow this answer of mine : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4640156/necessary-condition-for-invertible-integral-tansform/4640497#4640497

Comment: @Abezhiko Are the conditions in your answer the only conditions? What about the second part of my question?

Comment: The conditions depend on the smoothness you require; what do you expect ? As far as your second question is concerned, the matrix representation of such linear transforms is impractical, since it acts on an uncountably infinite-dimensional vector space; nevertheless, it will observe the obvious relation of invertibility $AA' = A'A = 1$.

Comment: I am not sure exactly sure what you mean by "smoothness". Regarding matrix representations, is there a bijection between the set of all integral transforms and the set of all invertible matrices?

Comment: I mean smoothness in the sense of the considered space you want to work with : $L^1$, $L^2$, a distribution or even operator space, etc. Regarding your second question, I must admit that I don't know, even if I doubt such a bijection exists, in the first place because of the awkward way to define such a group $-$ what ist the group of *all* invertible matrices, $GL\left(\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R}\right)$ ? $-$; indeed, we usually consider finite-dimensional matrix representations only.